# Java apache IOUtils: how to delete a file after read it into a byte array?

Tags: java

So I am trying to read a file into a byte array using apache common library, and then delete the file itself. But I cannot do it. can someone let me know why?

```
  File   aFile = new File("path_To_A_PDF_File");
  byte[] fileBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(aFile));
  boolean result = aFile.delete();

  System.out.println("is file " + aFile.getAbsolutePath() + " deleted? " + result);
```

How to I delete that file? Thanks

Comment: Note that you are leaking resources here. `toByteArray` does not close its `InputStream`.

Comment: yep. Thanks. I figured it out after posting the question. I thought the apache library will take care of closing the stream, apparently not.

Comment: @neo Just to note: the IOUtils class can't make the assumption that it can just close the stream - you might also feed it a stream which must NOT be closed once IOUtils is done with it. Sane software architecture is to let the class which opens resources also be responsible for cleaning them up.

Comment: Forgot to add: or use try-with-resources. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close the stream opened by: new FileInputStream(aFile)

Answer (score 0):

The [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class contains a method to help with this. Call [`deleteOnExit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) and let the JVM clean it up for you later.

```
aFile.deleteOnExit();
```

Per the linked Javadoc,

> Requests that the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname be deleted when the virtual machine terminates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still have the FileInputSteam open on aFile. Try IOUtils.closeQuietly() on it (you'll need to make it a local variable instead of anonymous as you have it now).